# Are those black spots on the inside of kaki safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, fruit, mold

I bought some kaki / sharon / persimmon (Rojo Brillante, from Spain) and left them for about a week. Now that i cut them open they are full of black and brown patches
[image]

What is this and is it safe to eat? It looks fine from the outside and doesnt affect the firmness of the flesh like mold or bruises usually do. Having tasted a small bit of "clean" and "dirty" parts, i found no significant difference in taste.
I found some brief descriptions of a "japanese chocolate persimmon" kind but the pictures looked quite different, either with a flat shape and uniform brown speckles or entirely rotten

Comment: Hard to tell from the pictures alone, but it looks just like a simple oxidation effects only, in which case it should be safe to eat.

Comment: They are well ripe. It should be ok !

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Kaki. And among some strains, this is commonly observed. The tree my grandfather had in his garden used to have the same patterns. I don't think this should be causing any food-safety concerns.